# Drawing a square on python turtle

Tags: python, draw, square

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTLVf.png)I'm a young French student.
I need your help. I have a silly python exercise that I can't solve because I'm a beginner. I am working on python 3.7. My teacher asks me to propose a programme that draws a square of 150 on each side filled in blue colour starting from the coordinates 0.0 (with the turtle module). I've been trying for several times but I can't manage it. If you could help me to solve it knowing that I really have very little knowledge. The commands available to me are :
re

```
set()
goto(x, y)
forward(distance)
backward(distance)
circle(radius)
up()
down()
colour(colour)
left(angle)
right(angle)
width(thickness)
begin_fill()
end_fill()
write(text)
done() or mainloop()
```

If you could help me with a very basic code thy.

Comment: Hey Thomas, welcome to stack overflow. Generally it is very helpful for us to know what you have tried and what specific error you are getting. Stack Overflow is not supposed to be a 'do my homework' kinda thing.

Comment: Hey Thomas, i'm suprised your teacher asked you to do that straightforward, you must have had some classes on iterations etc. What does your failed attemps look like ? Share your code ?!

Comment: I didn't know sorry, I just needed help. @griffin_cosgrove

Answer (score 0):

The code should look something like this:

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
x=0
t.fillcolor("blue")
t.begin_fill()
while x<4:
    t.forward(150)
    t.left(90)
    x+=1
t.end_fill()
turtle.done()
```

The turtle.done() acts as the mainloop() command.
This will create a square that is blue. if you want it to go faster, use the .speed command to make it go faster. Also, there are plenty of tutorials online, so i think those would be better for this situation.

Comment: when I try in python 3.7 they tell me SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Comment: oh sorry python 3.7 not 3.8

Answer (score 0):

```
#import library
from turtle import *

# set color
fillcolor("blue") 
  
# start filling area 
begin_fill() 
      
# draw the square 
for _ in range(4): 
   forward(150) 
   right(90) 
      
# ending the filling 
end_fill()
```

**remember to install python3-tk**